# format_string in icCube does not format null values

Tags: mdx, iccube

I was trying to display values that are null as 0 using format_string.

I currently have the following:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [test] AS null, FORMAT_STRING = '0.#;Neg (0.#);0.00;0.00'
SELECT
[test] ON COLUMNS
 FROM [Sales]
```

The fourth value (;0.00) should format the null values to zeros. I read that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084.aspx

Currently it shows nothing. It should show 0.00.

You can try it here: http://www.iccube.com/run-mdx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug ([ic3pub_159)](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-159) that is going to be fixed in the next version. As a workaround you can use the [coalesceEmpty MDX function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/CoalesceEmpty.php).

```
CoalesceEmpty( [MyValue] , 0.0 )
```